# /usr/bin/bash popups in Visual Studio Code (Git Bash)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, git-bash, background-process

I'm running VSC on my work machine that's running on Windows 10 Enterprise. I don't have sysadmin priviledges (although I fail to see how this would really be relevant in this case, but it's just contextual information that I can't install stuff on this machine - VSC was actually a suprise that I could install).

ANYWAY. When using VSC it throws every so often (usually when switching files I'm working on) a couple of open-and-immediately-close terminal popup screens that take the focus off the editor which is really annoying. Sometimes they even refuse to close and are left hanging.

What baffles me that they start with /usr/bin/bash ... and I'm on a Windows machine. The current processes that are stuck have the "--login -i remote --verbose" -options added. The stuck processes are titled as Git Bash, which kind of makes sense, but this happens EVEN when working on a project I have yet to put to Github.

Sure, they are background scripts but they open in the foreground. I'm even happy about the idea of taking away git functionality from my VSC installation alltogether and using Github desktop instead for commits, as I'm flying solo anyway.

So a) is there a fix for this or if not, b) how can I disable git integration in VSC?

Comment: ... have you installed Git For Windows?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs due wrong selection of the git bash exe.

Correct:

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`

Wrong:

`C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`

In my case I had to fix that in the windows Terminal app, where I added the wrong bash as well. Then in the *settings.json* of VsCode I had to edit the line for *git.path* like this

```
"git.path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\git.exe",
```